# JSON string evaluation with JavaScript, and getting it's value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, evaluation

I have this case (a JSON string returned by my server):

```
{"success": true, "users": [1, 3, 4, 8]}
```

However, when using this kind of request, I'd get that response as a "string":

```
var availableUsers = $.ajax({
    url: absPath + '/users/findUsers',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {contents: $('#messageTo').val()},
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

With: `alert(typeof(availableUsers));` I'd get: `string` return value from `typeof`.

When doing this:

`window.eval(availableUsers);` It won't be evaluated as expected, to a JavaScript Object.

How can I get the valid JSON response (using, async: false) converted to a JavaScript accessable Object or how can I propertly evaluate the string returned from the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the content type header returned from the request to /users/findUsers

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a `success` callback here? Even with `async:true`, this would likely be a) more legible, and b) more likely to do what you expect. I don't think jQuery's automatic JSON-parsing will kick in with `.responseText`.

Comment: Can you use `jQuery.parseJSON`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the content type of your request to application/json
read more here: [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the JSON object in a callback? Check the `success` setting.

```
$.ajax({
     url: absPath + '/users/findUsers',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {contents: $('#messageTo').val()},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
         var availableUsers = data;
         alert(typeof availableUsers);
     },
     async: false 
});
```

With the callback, you may do what ever you want with the object you got from the server.

Comment: my availableUsers is a global variable and I need it outside that anonymous function under the $.ajax({})! $.parseJSON helped the trick ;)

Comment: @Commando: Then just remove the `var`. But honestly you should not use synchronous requests. They are not needed in most cases.